# Terraform postgres import failing

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

Hi I’m importing a resource but it’s failing. I’m not sure what the issue is. Can someone point me how to fix this error.

I tried by setting `sslmode = "require"`, got the same error.
my ssl is `on` in database and force.ssl is `off`

Terraform v0.12.20

provider.aws v2.58.0
provider.postgresql v1.5.0
Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version

My module:
locals.tf:

```
pgauth_dbs = var.env == "prod" ? var.prod_dbs : var.stage_dbs
```

variables.tf

```
variable "stage_dbs" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["host_configs", "staging", "staging_preview"]
}
```

Provider

```
provider "postgresql" {
  version = ">1.4.0"
  alias            = "pg1"
  host             = aws_db_instance.name.address
  port             = aws_db_instance.name.port
  username         = var.username
  password         = var.master_password
  expected_version = aws_db_instance.name.engine_version 
  sslmode          = "disable"
  connect_timeout  = 15
}
```

module:

```
 resource "postgresql_database" "pgauth_dbs" {
  provider = postgresql.pg1
  for_each = toset(local.pgauth_dbs)
  name     = each.value
  owner    = "postgres"
}
```

Root-Module:

```
  module rds {
      source = ../../../../tf_module_rds
      username          = "postgres"
      master_password   = data.aws_kms_secrets.secrets_password.plaintext["password"]
      engine_version    = "11.5"
      instance_class    = "db.m5.xlarge"
      allocated_storage = "300"
      storage_type      = "gp2"    
}

terraform import module.rds.postgresql_database.name_dbs[“host_configs”] host_configs

module.rds.postgresql_database.name_dbs[“host_configs”]: Importing from ID “host_configs”…
module.rds.postgresql_database.name_dbs[“host_configs”]: Import prepared!
Prepared postgresql_database for import
module.rds.postgresql_database.name_dbs[\“host_configs”\]: Refreshing state… [id=host_configs]

Error: could not start transaction: pq: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
```

Comment: Your Terraform snippets are full of missing bits, presumably from heavy editing. Examples include the root module not having `module "rds" {` or the closing brace, the `pg1` postgres provider isn't defined, your locals.tf isn't valid HCL and you are missing a trailing quote on `host_configs` in the `stage_dbs` variable default. Can you please read the [mcve] guide on what a good, minimally reproducible example looks like? That will make it much easier for people to be able to help you and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Provider should point to instance's username and not variable

```
provider "postgresql" {
  version = ">1.4.0"
  alias            = "pg1"
  host             = aws_db_instance.name.address
  port             = aws_db_instance.name.port
  username         = aws_db_instance.name.username
  password         = aws_db_instance.name.password
  database         = aws_db_instance.name.name
  expected_version = aws_db_instance.name.engine_version 
  sslmode          = "disable"
  connect_timeout  = 15
}
```